# How i can add some jvm options to arquillian test

Tags: testing, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

Its possible to add some jvm options to embedded glassfish using arquillian ?

I need to add that jvm options:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java properties on Glassfish are configured in *domain.xml*. Since you are running an embedded Glassfish, you don't really have a *domain.xml* file you could modify. You can try to do this in *arquillian.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/arquillian-1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/arquillian-1.0 http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian-1.0.xsd">
    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>
    </engine>
    <container qualifier="glassfish" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="configurationXml">file:src/test/resources/domain.xml</property>
            ...
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

The *configurationXml* property is used to pass the configuration file to use for the embedded insance. See also https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/GlassFish+3.1+-+Embedded. *domain.xml* itself has a section for JVM arguments.